# Python loop that shouldn't work but does anyways

Tags: python, loops

So I decided to learn python this weekend and I started with my default hello world, the prime solver.  This code shouldn't work... But for whatever reason it does (for numbers 5 and higher.)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
a = 2
while a < 65535:
    c = 0
    a = a + 1
    b = 2
    while b != a:
        if a % b == 0:
            #print a, "is not prime. LCD is ", b
            break
        b = b + 1
     if a - 1 == b: c = 1
 if c == 1: print a, " is prime"
```

The next to the last conditional should always be false, and yet somehow a -1 == b for all primes 5 and up.

Can someone point out this noob's mistake, because I'm obviously missing something easily described.

Answers further below.

Comment: I copied and pasted this into a file and it prints out prime numbers as described.

Comment: its really hard to read code.. could you fix indent?

Comment: Actually, shouln't the condition be true also for `a=3`? When you get there with `a=3` (the first time you ever do), `b=2`. So basically it works for *all* primes you test for (you don't test for 2...)

Comment: Besides being stupid, the above can be made much easier to read:

Comment: For what it's worth, you shouldn't have edited the question to a working state. Doing this would eliminate the usefulness of SO.

Comment: Sorry, the addage "You must be new here" is pretty true.  I will return it to the baroken state for historical reasons.

Comment: And welcome to Stack Overflow :) Questions that are slightly deeper are more warmly received. You may like to try to Python Tutor mailing list for these types of questions: http://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/tutor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `a` is not prime, it has atleast two proper divisors, and of one of them must be smaller than the square root (or both are the square root). If `b` reaches `sqrt(a)+1`, then `a` must be prime. So if `b` reaches `a - 1`, you can be *pretty sure* it's prime. You could also replace it by `if a - 3 == b`, or `a / 2` (but this might not work for the smaller primes).

Comment: Yeah, but functionally it reaches the solution, which is why I've tried to keep it as the hello world default.  

It typically involves a nested loop so it gives me just enough to start doing damage to some cycles, and it's good enough mathematically to solve for primes > 2.

Comment: @Ori - Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Anyway, I tried to explain why "The next to the last conditional should" be true for primes and primes only. That used to be the question, right?

Comment: Yeah it's there now.  And you nailed it dead on.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work for me; after changing `65535` to `1024` and removing the `" is prime"` portion (so I can run the results right into `factor(1)`), the output looks like this:

```
$ ./prime.py | xargs -n1 factor > /tmp/list ; wc -l list
170 list
$ head list
5: 5
7: 7
11: 11
13: 13
17: 17
19: 19
23: 23
29: 29
31: 31
37: 37
```

Are you sure you copy-and-pasted it correctly? I find one-space indents miserable reading, and perhaps you mis-copied or mis-formatted?

Comment: Yeah I fixed it, I was doing something unnecessary, based on my incomplete knowledge of the language.

Comment: The original problem was that it was indeed working.

Comment: Heh, now I see new edits :) got it. Hehe.